# freeform pro 4 and honeepot, spam still coming through

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms, solspace, spam

I implemented honeepot (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hon-ee-pot-captcha) for two freeform pro forms I have on my 2.6.1 EE website and it cut down the spam drastically, but some are still getting thru.

Is there anything else that I can do to combat it?

I do not want to have the users have to fill in a captcha field to submit the form.

I tried honeepot over snaptcha because its free. What do you think of snaptcha? Is that something will cut down on spam more so than honeepot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Snaptcha](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha) has some additional features over [Honeepot](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hon-ee-pot-captcha) to better prevent spam submissions. Snaptcha's "medium" and "high" settings require that javascript be enabled, which blocks spambots (they don't use JS). The "high" setting also only allows the form to be submitted once, which helps prevent multiple spam submissions.

I also highly recommend [Low Nospam](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-nospam) paired with an [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) license. It checks every form submission against a database of known spammers and spam content. If it fails the test, the submission fails. I've never used [Freeform Anti-Spam](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform-anti-spam) so I don't know if they conflict, though.

Another excellent free add-on is [VZ Bad Behavior](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/vz-bad-behavior). This works a lot like Low Nospam in that it checks against a database of known spammers, but VZ Bad Behavior actually prevents spammers from even *viewing* your site, let alone submitting a form.

Also don't forget to check out [EllisLab's recommendations for preventing spam natively](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/spam_protection.html).

Even with all of these options the occasional, clever human spammer will get through. But so few that it's negligible. Just add their IP address to the [EE Blacklist](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/blacklist/) to prevent them from posting again.

Answer (score 1):

i normally also setup http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freeform-anti-spam and http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nospam to help.
However, spam allways gets through occasionally